# background image not displaying css/html

Tags: html, css

This is probably a really simple problem that I'm guessing has a very obvious but stupid solution but I am not seeing it. I am trying to get an image to become a tiled background and for some reason the image is not appearing nor am I getting errors. I have checked permissions and set all files and folders to 777. Can someone point out the problem for me thanks.

My CSS file:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/main_background.png");
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
    </head>

<body>

    <div id="main_container">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It might be the reason that the image isn't found in the directory/your are providing wrong url/the styleshet isn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is in images folder and css is in css folder.

`images/main_background.png` means that images folder is inside the css folder, but it is not.

write this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/main_background.png"); 
}
```

OR

```
body {
    background-image: url("/images/main_background.png"); 
}
```

Comment: Wow that was dumb of me I've been scratching my head for a half hour screwing with this problem. Thanks I would have thought chromes inspector would have given me a file not found error but I wasn't getting one

Comment: Welcome.. checking console is the best way to understand errors.